# How to read a high voltage signal with Arduino (wirelessly)

Tags: current, sensor, hall-effect, detection

I am trying to build a tachometer for my motorcycle, something like this:
https://youtu.be/GmLaNy2NBcQ

What I need to determine is the time between two spark plug "sparks". How could I determine whether there is current flowing through the spark plug wire or not? (On/off)

I thought of using inductive pickup but I am not really sure how to do it... Would a Hall effect sensor do the job?

The bike has no tachometer from the factory and no tachometer wiring or anything (2004 Cagiva Raptor 125).

Comment: Can you educate me a bit here?  Does a motorcycle use a magneto to generate the spark?  If so, you might want to stay away from all that high voltage and (as you have suggested) use a (small) inductive pickup to sense the magneto magnet pass at a different location than where the magneto is.  You can try a hall effect sensor, but I am not sure if it recovers fast enough between exposures to a magnetic field.  You'll have to dig through the hall effect sensor's specifications.  If you confirm the magneto setup in motorcycles I can transfer this question/suggestion to an answer.

Comment: You are right. I thought of this other solution: i could stick a small magnet on the flywheel and use a hall effect sensor with it...

Comment: You could use some magnetic pickups like the ones used in stroboscope lights, but wouldn't it be easier to get the signal from the ignition module?

Comment: @MarceloEspinozaVargas I am not really sure on how to manipulate the CDI... there is this other option: the ignition coil uses 12v at the primary winding(i m not sure how everything is named but i know how this works). It uses a pulsating ground (again, not sure this is the right term). So basically it is a 12v switch that goes on and off really fast. I think i could step down the voltage using a voltage divider and read it with the Arduino. I tried it before but one of the resistors got pretty hot in the end and started turning black, and my code was wrong. Do you guys think this idea is ok?

Comment: Adding something to the flywheel may put it out of balance.  And, usually, there is already a magnet on the flywheel for either a magneto or for electronic spark timing.  I was thinking of possibly added an inductive pickup to sense the existing magnet.

Comment: Most electronic tachometers receive the signal from the negative pin of the coil, so this might be the easiest way. Don't try using a voltage divider because the resistance of the coil is really low, so you'd need very low resistors with a huge current rating, instead try using some op amps to adequate those 12V

Comment: @st2000 I undersrand. There are some dedicated flywheel magnets existent on the market but not for 125cc bikes as these flywheels are really small. I thought that it would harm the performance of the engine as even though the magnet has a low weight, if it spins at rpm's as high as 12.000 it may go out ot balance. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @MarceloEspinozaVargas  Sadly i have no experience with OP amps and i am not really an experimented electronist... i am just an enthusiastic high school student... could i just use a step down converter? Aren't those PWM based so that means very little resistance?

Comment: Ok, how's about this then.  When I was a kid, I used to hold neon bulbs next to a spark plug wire.  The bulb's leads in my hand.  The leaking electrical field around the spark plug wire would be enough to light the bulb's gas. You might try this and connect the bulb's leads to the bike's ground (chassis).  Now, use black heat shrink tubing and construct a device that optically couples the neon bulb with a photo diode connected to an Arduino.

Comment: @st2000 i understand... also, please excuse my grammar mistakes... i am not a native english speaker

Comment: You may need to distance the photo diode and Arduino form the spark plug wire using optical fiber.  I imaging the electrical noise next to the spark plug wire will cause all kinds of problems with the photo diode and Arduino.

Comment: @st2000 That is a brilliant idea!!! I definitely got to try it! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/t35dzxi69/check that connection, with that optocoupler you could run safe your arduino, just add a pull up resistor between your arduino input pin and 5V

Comment: @MarceloEspinozaVargas can i replace that IC with something else? It's pretty difficult to find one of those in my country...

Comment: Keep on the good work!!! Something else, since you're working with Arduino and vehicles electronics, always try to find the most stable voltage source and the best ground possible to supply power to your arduino, and put some big enough capacitors as close to your arduino as possible.

Comment: @MarceloEspinozaVargas i have a bit of a question on this subject: where am  i supposed to use capacitors? I figure that using them on the input makes no sense as they would mess up the readings, and the power source for the Arduino is the battery, which is stable enough... i am still a newb in electronics, could you explain, please?

Comment: Believe me, the battery is less of stable as it's supposed to be xD, generally the alternator has two output voltages, one that goes to the battery and power devices and other one that goes to the dashboard, use that supply. The capacitors are supposed to go between the arduino supply voltage and ground, although I guess that the arduino board has the capacitors already.

Comment: @MarceloEspinozaVargas i did not know that... wow, thanks. But... given the fact that the alternator is working fine and so does the charging relay/ circuit (we call it relay around here) isn't the battery supposed to be fed voltage? Basically the same thing you said. If the battery is wrecked (or disconnected) the leads that were supposed to go to it are still being fed the 13.7 volts (or something like that), right? Afterwards i will step it down to safe and stable 5 volts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60276/discussion-between-marcelo-espinoza-vargas-and-andrei-grigore).

Answer (score 1):

When I was a kid, I used to hold neon bulbs next to a spark plug wire. The bulb's leads in my hand. The leaking electrical field around the spark plug wire would be enough to light the bulb's gas. You might try this and connect the bulb's leads to the bike's ground (chassis). Now, use black heat shrink tubing and construct a device that optically couples the neon bulb with a photo diode connected to an Arduino. You may need to distance the photo diode and Arduino form the spark plug wire using optical fiber. I imaging the electrical noise next to the spark plug wire will cause all kinds of problems with the photo diode and Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Tachometers are implemented in many ways.

Fundamentally the transition pulse from ignition is stretched with a precision one shot.  THe duration must be less than the max frequency time interval.

The amplitude of the stretch pulse must be a regulated voltage. ( e.g. Logic level) driven by LDO.

The output of these pulses is then low pass filtered to obtain the average DC voltage proportional to RPM.

Then the Tachometer is just a uA ammeter with a sensitivity something like 20~50kOhm/V which then only needs a series R to be added to convert full scale RPM to Voltage to current.

All LPF's  adds delay or latency according to the passband breakpoint.   Ripple at the lowest RPM can be computed to be at least 30dB down.  If you want the fastest response with the lowest jitter at low RPM, you simply use a 5th order switched-cap filter IC or a 5th order quad Op Amp using the TI free filter software.

If you don't understand these fundamentals, then ask. If you do then you can appreciate the fine details on response time, accuracy and dither at low RPM in ANY design you find on the web.

Wireless pickup is trivial with twisted pair wire with a small loop near the ignition area and then terminated with 100 Ohms.  Logic gates may be used to square up the pulse with hysteresis.

Comment: What is the transition pulse? The actual spark?

Comment: Yes the ignition wire today is limited by the carbon wire resistance but even a 1:1 wire ratio acting as a current transformer can transform this into a low voltage with a small burden resistor like 100 ohms. THis can easily be amplified in many ways and with Series RC  coupling and diode clamps be used to directly activate a Schmitt trigger